# Run an ecosystem in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We are developing a fairly complex app that has a node server that talks to a CouchDB instance, another node server that talks a redis instance, a third node server that talks to both of the other node servers, and a Redis store that all three talk to.

Developing locally requires installing and running CouchDB, two redis instances, and the three node apps. This really isn't a problem, but we want a dev to be able to come onto the project and start developing right away without much of a barrier to entry. I'd like to create a docker container that runs all of these things so they can just build and run it and start developing without any trouble.

I'm reading over the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) document, and it mentions that you should run only *one* process per container -- effectively we have six processes. It suggests using container linking for dependent services too, but in this case it seems like you would still need six separate docker containers / instances and have to run each of them on their own and then link them. I'd like to simplify this further.

Is there a standard for creating a repo of multiple Dockerfiles that all interact with one another. Is there a simple way to link, run, and build them all simultaneously? Would this be a good idea, or would it be better to just run all of these processes in one container using `supervisor`?

Comment: Some months ago, I saw this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Glk5d5WP6MI) about 'docker in production', it give me some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) (formerly Fig), which lets you orchestrate the creation and linking of multiple containers. There are other ways to do this but Compose is the "official" way that gets the most care.

You can essentially have it create exactly what you want and handle the linking for you, so a simple "docker-compose up -d" and "docker-compose stop" will be the bulk of what your developers need to get going.

As for managing multiple Dockerfiles, you should commit them to the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) once they are built. From there, your docker-compose.yml can pull each image down to the developer machine. You'll also likely be able to re-use official repositories instead of writing your own Dockerfiles, simply customizing them with ENV variables passed in through Compose. For example, the [Official Redis Image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/redis/) can even accept a custom redis.conf file without the need for your own custom image/container.

Comment: This is great. The only snag we've run into so far is that the node apps all come from private git repos. Any suggestion for installing the repos via a Dockerfile? I think devs could then edit the contents via mounting, but is there anything else I should be aware of in that regard?

Comment: In development when you want the contents to be editable, you would generally run a container with the dependencies only, then mount your application code with a volume from the local system. This way, developers can make changes with their usual tools and environment and the Docker containers will see those changes in real-time.